# My new WordPress blog keeps refreshing in Chrome browser

Tags: errors, browser-compatibility

My new WordPress [blog]: http://wuyajun.info/ keeps refreshing in Chrome browser, gets loading error in Firefox, but works normal in IE.

Plugins installed that may cause the problem: Facebook AWD All in One.

Hope someone can help me on this, thank you.

Nathan

---

Nov 15, 2011 update

Just to clarify the refreshing problem was not due to PHP cache, for my situation.
The function "Activate FB Connect" of WP plugin "Facebook AWD All in One" caused this problem. After I deactivates this function (NOT the whole plugin), this problem gets resolved. Hope this followup can help.

Comment: Can't reproduce, `Chrome 14.0.835.202 (Official Build 103287) / Linux`, and `Firefox 3.6.23` have you tried clearing your cache?

Comment: Yes, I have cleared the cache and tried on different computers and browsers. Problem still exists on Chrome 14.0.835.202 / Windows (refreshing), and Firefox 3.0.7 / Windows (Loading error).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned, clear your cache. I have no problem with Firefox 7.01 or Iron (Chromium )  on Windows. I would also deactivate all plugins and see if that fixes it. If so then activate them one by one and see if you can find which one causes the problem. What happens if you use another theme? Do you have another computer to test on? The idea is to find out WHY the issue is happening and narrow it down a bit.

Comment: After I cleared cache, the site stops refreshing now. I don't know why this didn't work on my other PC where I also cleared the cache. Anyway, the problem is solved and thanks @BandonRandon!